# How to update an ImageView from server very often?

Tags: android

I am using Picasso Library to load image from server. I would like to update the image about 5-10 times per second. It doesn't even load with 1 frame/s

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
        while (refreshImage) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(getImageURL).into(videoImage);
                    }
                    }, 1000);


                }
            });
        }

        return null;
     }
```

Is there any other way to update an ImageView with a fast frame rate?

Comment: Does getImageURL change at that rate as well?

Comment: no. the server generates at 10 images/sec for getImageURL

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following thread functionality

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (Chcek online condition here) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do your task here...
                    }
                });
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I've inserted this inside my doInBackground method, but it does not refresh images, I just get the first one as usually. Maybe there is a library or some other type of view? What if if try to output the image inside a webView and refresh at the rate I need?